# How can TranslatableMarkup string output be modified in the theme?

Tags: theming, 8

In comments there's `submitted`, which is an object from the [Translatable Markup Class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!StringTranslation!TranslatableMarkup.php/class/TranslatableMarkup/8.2.x); run through `kint()` it looks like this:
[image: kint output of submitted from comment.html.twig]

I want it to say `By @username <time>$datetime</time>`, but haven't been able to figure out how it wants me to modify it?

I can get the arguments in preprocess with `$variables['submitted']->getArguments();` but that seems less cool.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: That's how you do it, get the arguments and build a new one with `t()`. You can't change this object, it has no setters.

Comment: Seems like it'd be cooler if you could change the string given that you don't want to change any of the tokens, don't see why it has to be read only; but oh well!